# Unicode characters are boxes in Geraldo/ReportLab generated PDF

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, reportlab, geraldo

I'm running into some Unicode related issues when generating PDF reports using Geraldo and ReportLab.

When Unicode strings containing Asian characters are passed into the report, they appear in the output PDF as black boxes. This example (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2627296/report.pdf) was generated using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from geraldo import Report, ReportBand, ObjectValue
from geraldo.generators import PDFGenerator

class UnicodeReport(Report):    
    title = 'Report'

    class band_detail(ReportBand):
        elements = [ObjectValue(attribute_name='name')]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    objects = [{'name': u'한국어/조선말'}, {'name': u'汉语/漢語'}, {'name': u'オナカップ'}]    
    rpt = UnicodeReport(queryset=objects)
    rpt.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename='/tmp/report.pdf')
```

I'm using Python 2.7.1, Geraldo 0.4.14 and ReportLab 2.5. System is Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. The .oy file is also UTF-8 encoded. The black boxes are visible when the PDF is viewed in Document Viewer 2.32.0, Okular 0.12.2 and Adobe Reader 9.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using [embedded fonts](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/370548)?  Is the [asian font pack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WSDCD9813D-3347-4781-810C-5DE967647580.w.html) installed on the machine you're testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the font name as in the official example "[Additional Fonts](http://www.geraldoreports.org/docs/examples/additional-fonts.html)". Use `additional_fonts` and `default_style`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from geraldo import Report, ReportBand, ObjectValue
from geraldo.generators import PDFGenerator

class UnicodeReport(Report):    
    title = 'Report'
    additional_fonts = {
        'wqy': '/usr/share/fonts/wqy-zenhei/wqy-zenhei.ttc'
    }
    default_style = {'fontName': 'wqy'}

    class band_detail(ReportBand):
        elements = [ObjectValue(attribute_name='name')]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    objects = [{'name': u'한국어/조선말'}, {'name': u'汉语/漢語'}, {'name': u'オナカップ'}]    
    rpt = UnicodeReport(queryset=objects)
    rpt.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename='/tmp/report.pdf')
```

`ObjectValue()` also has a named parameter `style`:

```
elements = [ObjectValue(attribute_name='name', style={'fontName': 'wqy'})]
```

This font is open source and can be downloaded here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wqy/files/ (I think it's shipped with Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: thanks for that, now the Asian characters show up! In my setup, had to run 'sudo apt-get install ttf-wqy-zenhei' as wqy-zenhei is not a standard CD release (it is on the DVD release). this installs the font to '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-zenhei.ttc'.